# What is the difference between Usul-fiqh/Usul-Din and Quranic studies and Sharia and Islamic Studies?

Tags: sharia, usool-ul-fiqh

Is there actually any difference between Usul-Din and Usul-Fiqh?

Which one should I go for if want to become a mufti?

Comment: Osol-ad-Dyn seems to be a very wage term the others are well defined.

Answer (score 1):

### From what I know, Usul-al-Din is a Shia belief and Usul-al-Fiqh is both Sunni and Shia belief

---

Usul-al-Din means **(Principles of the Religion)** while Usul-al-Fiqh means **(Principles of Jurisprudence)**.

---

### 1. Usul-al-Din

From [shiastudies.org](http://shiastudies.org/article/principles-of-the-religion):

> **The Principles of Religion (Usul al-Din) which outline the essential beliefs in accordance with the Qur’an and the teachings of the Twelve Imams**
>
> The Principles of the Religion according to Twelver Shi’a Islam are:
>
> - **Belief in Oneness and Unity of God:** Al-Tawhid
> - **Belief in Divine Justice:** Al-Adl
> - **Belief in Prophethood:** Al-Nubuwah
> - **Belief in Imams:** Al-Imamah
> - **Belief in Day of Resurrection:** Al-Ma’ad

In Sunni Islam, the equal would be [iman mufassal](http://www.islamawakened.com/DurusulQuran/as-sidq/faith.html).

---

### 2. Usul-al-Fiqh

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Islamic_jurisprudence) writes:

> **Principles of Islamic jurisprudence** otherwise known as **Uṣūl al-fiqh** (Arabic: أصول الفقه‎‎) is the **study and critical analysis of the origins, sources, and principles upon which Islamic jurisprudence is based.**

The four main sources for Usul-al-Fiqh are:

- Quran
- Sunnah
- Ijma
- Qiyas

They are analysed along with secondary sources:

> - Istihsan
> - Masali Mursala
> - Ihsaan (spiritual excellence, virtue)
> - Istidlaal
> - Urf (local custom or pre-existing law)
> - Aql (reason or intellect)
> - Sadd al-dharai
> - Shara man qablana
> - Ijma al-ummah (consensus of the worldwide Muslim community)
> - Ijma khulafah al-rashideen (consensus of the first four caliphs)
> - Ijma ahl al-medina (consensus of the Muslims of Medina, as reflected in early hadith collections, e. g. the Muwatta of Imam Malik ibn Anas)
> - Ijma al-ullama (consensus of scholars of Islamic law)
> - Ijma ahl al-hali wa al-aqd

These are used to discuss:

> - General evidences and principles (adillah ijmalliya wa al-qawaid)
> - Resolution of conflict and discrepancy (ta'adal wa tarjeeh)
> - Determination of rules and adoption/emulation of rules (ijtihad wa taqlid)
> - Islamic Law (hukm shari)

The Jafari Akhbari Shias believe that the Quran and Sunnah are the only sources of law while the Jafari Usuli Shias use Ijtihaad.

---

**Conclusion:** The difference between these two is that Usul-al-Din is principle of religion and beliefs while Usul-al-Fiqh is the principles of Islamic law, i.e. Sharia.

If one wants to become a Mufti, it depends whether you follow Sunni or Shia. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mufti):

> A mufti (/ˈmʌfti/; Arabic: مفتي‎‎ muftī; Turkish: müftü) is an Islamic scholar who interprets and expounds Islamic law (Sharia and fiqh).

Therefore one will **need to learn Usul-al-Fiqh**.

And Allah knows best.

---

Comment: My knowledge is that Usul Al- Din is not only a shia subject... Read more here: [أصول الدين](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86)

Comment: I don't know Arabic